# TextCtrl scrollbar unusable until window is resized

Tags: python, wxpython

**Solved**:
Thanks to Aya's answer below I now know that the issue was caused by `self.panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)` on line 18. I created a panel and didn't attach anything to it. The original issue description is still below for reference.

My Google-fu has failed me. I'm building the text editor that you can find here, written in Python with wxPython:

https://github.com/joshsaintjacque/py-ed/blob/master/pyed.py

The issue that I'm running into is this: when I open a text file (the only functionality built in at this point) that's larger than the viewable area in the TextCtrl the scroll bar remains disabled until the window is re-sized, then it works fine.

I know that the act of re-sizing the window is running some command that I'm neglecting to include in my OpenFile function (or perhaps in **init**), but I can't figure out what.
Any thoughts anyone has that could lead me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: +1 for linking to complete source code. After I commented out the line "self.panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)" your code works fine for me, on win32. Did you perhaps mean to make the text control a child of this panel?

Comment: @Aya You are brilliant! It works perfectly after removing this line. I will update the original post. Also, if you submit this as an answer I will accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Done. I also added a few other points to the answer which may or may not be useful, but after having spent several months battling with wxPython myself, I know how painful it can be. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

+1 for including a link to the full source code - makes it so much easier to test.

I couldn't reproduce the fault you describe on wxPython 2.8.12 on Win32, but upon running your code, I found a seemingly extraneous `wx.Panel` object being created on `pyed.py` line 18...

```
self.panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
```

...which seems to be interfering with the correct operation of the program. After commenting out that line, it seems to work fine.

---

A couple of other things I noticed: line 56...

```
self.SetTitle("PyEd - Editing ... " + filename)
```

...should probably be put in the preceding if-block, otherwise you'll get an error if the user clicks "Cancel" on the `wx.FileDialog`, and on line 16...

```
wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, 'PyEd', (-1, -1), wx.Size(640, 480))
```

...if you use keyword args rather than positional args...

```
wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=parent, id=id, title='PyEd', size=wx.Size(640, 480))
```

...you needn't bother re-specifying the default value for the window position, which is also slightly safer, in case the wxPython developers decide to change the defaults in a future version.

You can also factor out constant values, and the optional creation of the `wx.Size` object to reduce that line to...

```
wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=None, title='PyEd', size=(640, 480))
```

---

Finally, with regards to IDs: in most cases you'll probably find they're of little use. Where they come in handy is where you want many similar controls, and it makes more sense to have them handled by a single event handler function.

Consider this example...

```
def create_buttons(parent):
    parent.button1 = wx.Button(label='Button 1')
    parent.button2 = wx.Button(label='Button 2')
    parent.button3 = wx.Button(label='Button 3')

    parent.button1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, on_button_1)
    parent.button2.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, on_button_2)
    parent.button3.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, on_button_3)

def on_button_1(event):
    print 'You clicked button 1'

def on_button_2(event):
    print 'You clicked button 2'

def on_button_3(event):
    print 'You clicked button 3'
```

...which is fine, but if you need, say, 100 buttons, you may prefer to implement it like this...

```
def create_buttons(parent):
    parent.buttons = [wx.Button(id=i, label='Button %d' % i) for i in range(100)]
    parent.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, on_button)

def on_button(event):
    button_id = event.GetId()
    print 'You clicked button %d' % button_id
```

Oh, and be careful using `id` as a variable name, because it's also a Python built-in function name.

Comment: Thanks again for your feedback, just wanted to let you know that I've implemented all of the changes you suggested in the repo. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you're not setting the min or max size hints for the window, nor are you calling `Self.Fit()` to fit the box sizer to the window size (or is it the other way round? I'm rusty on my wxPython...)

Right where you call self.SetSizer(sizer), you should be able to fix this by adding:

```
self.Fit()
self.SetSizeHintSz(minSize=wx.Size(640, 480))
```

You may be able to get around the separate call to self.Fit() by using `self.SetSizerAndFit()`

(edited for spelling.)

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to look at this.

I added the code right after self.SetSizer(sizer) but on running the program I get an object has no attribute 'SetSizeHintSz' error.